# I have to run my macro twice, how to fix?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that copy/paste values into a format I use for homework. It all works as intended, but I have to run it twice for it to be perfect.

how do I fix this and just run it once to work?

```
Sub WellLogAutomator()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

n = Worksheets("Info").Range("C10:C100").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Sheets("Type Data Here").Select
Range("A1:B5").Select
Selection.Copy

For i = 1 To n - 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i

Sheets("Info").Select
Cells(10, 3).Select

For x = 0 To n - 1
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Cells(2, 11).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=x, columnOffset:=0).Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Type Data Here").Select
    Cells(1, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2 * x).Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next x

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("H2:H65").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("I2:I65").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please define perfect.

Comment: What does it do differently the second time?

Comment: The first time I run it, about half of the desired values are put into place. For some reason when I run it twice, all of my desired values are put into place. The top comment here with a counter and a DoAgain, works.

Comment: You need to do a google search for "Dimension" and learn how to use "Variable Types" . Also, search for how not to use "Select". 
The first part of your code copies the range A1 thru B5 on worksheet "Type Data Here", then moves 2 columns to the right and paste the copied range over and over every 2 columns for 89 times into the same sheet.  Search for how to use activecell; when you copied your range in "Type Data Here" you made A1 the activecell, These are just the issues in the first 11 lines. Clean up your code and then use F8 to step through it to see what each line of code is doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, it will run your code twice using a counter:

```
Sub WellLogAutomator()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim counter as Integer

counter = 0

DoAgain:
n = Worksheets("Info").Range("C10:C100").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Sheets("Type Data Here").Select
Range("A1:B5").Select
Selection.Copy

For i = 1 To n - 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i

Sheets("Info").Select
Cells(10, 3).Select

For x = 0 To n - 1
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Cells(2, 11).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=x, columnOffset:=0).Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Type Data Here").Select
    Cells(1, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2 * x).Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next x

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("H2:H65").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("I2:I65").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

If counter = 0 then
    counter = counter + 1
    goto DoAgain
else
    exit sub
end if

End Sub
```